# Code detects string as having duplicate letters, even when it does not

Tags: java, loops

I wrote a program to check whether a word does not have any duplicate letters. There are two problems I am having:
1 - I wrote this in object oriented code and I am having an issue calling my main method.
2-  When I had the code in one method - not broken up into pieces - the Boolean was not changing base on my checkLetters method. The output was the same - no matter what the test value was.
I am a java beginner and I would appreciate any advice.
Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class uniqueLetters
{
boolean isUnique;
char temp;
int i = 0;
String str;
char[] letters;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  testWord testing = new testWord();
}   

private void testWord()
{
 getArray();
 checkLetters();
 getStatement();
}

private void getArray()
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter your word:");
  str = keyboard.nextLine();
  letters = str.toCharArray();

}

private boolean checkLetters()
{
  boolean isUnique = true;

  for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < letters.length; j++)
     {
     if (letters[i] == letters[j])
     isUnique = false;   
     } 

  }
  return isUnique;
}

private void getStatement()
{
if (checkLetters())
  System.out.print("This word has all unique letters");
else 
  System.out.print("This word has duplicate letters");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you loop you do

```
for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < letters.length; j++)
 {
 if (letters[i] == letters[j])
 isUnique = false;   
 break;
 } 

}
```

but as the second loop is also starting at `0`, then it will always find a duplicate.

try

```
for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
 for (int j = i + 1; j < letters.length; j++)
 {
 if (letters[i] == letters[j])
 isUnique = false;   
 } 

}
```

Also, as you are calling `checkLetters` from `getStatement` then you do not need to call it from the `testWord` method.

Also as `testWorld` is a method not a class, you should not instantiate it, just call it.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I got it to work! I converted the code back to having it all in the main method until I am clearer on OOP. I also fixed the nested loop so that is was only started comparing the values in the array after the previous iterations start point.